# Using imagettftext in php appengine (font selection)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, imagettftext

I'm trying to create an image **from google's php appengine** that contains some text  rendered using the **imagettftext** php function. I have to **especify a font file name** and it's path to the function but i don't know how to access my static fonts directory from php script as scripts are stored separately from static files when i deploy the application.

This is the relevant code from my php script:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth, $imgHeight);
imagealphablending($image, false);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$black = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0,0,0, 0);
$font = './font/Allerta-Regular.ttf';
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparency);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagealphablending($image, true);
imagettftext($image, $fontSize, $angle, 100, 100, $black, $font, "Test text");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

The directory structure is something like this:
- root
    - js
    - css
    - font
    - img
Where php script is in the root folder and font files are in font folder.

The code above **works on my local PC but does not work when i deploy to the server** as imagettftext can't find the font and a error message is raised. Using URL full path does not work neither as imagettftext needs a local file path.

I've tried $font = '/font/Allerta-Regular.ttf' (without the initial dot) also but no luck.

I know that i can use "Google Cloud Storage" service but i don't want to hire it and duplicate files as this fonts are used from my js files also.

**How can i specify the font in PHP app engine to use with imagettftext?**

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: Just a message saying that font can't be found.

Comment: Right. Can you include that?

Comment: Sure @andrewj, that's the response i get with error_get_last() executed just after imagettftext call:  

`Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => imagettftext(): Invalid font filename [file] => /base/data/home/apps/s~ciplayerweb/1.3714147623940239791/findy.php [line] => 191 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved. As [app.yaml configuration page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers) says:

> For efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files separately
>   from application files. Static files are not available in the
>   application's file system. **If you have data files that need to be read
>   by the application code, the data files must be application files**, and
>   must not be matched by a static file pattern.

So i created a new "scriptfont" folder and defined a new entry in app.yaml file to say that the fonts will be loaded from the script, and not served to the browser:

```
- url: /scriptfont/(.*)
  script: /scriptfont/\1
```

Now, all files inside this folder can be used by php scripts.

Comment: Do you serve these fonts from your application? If not, then you should not have this or need this.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have to declare anything in the app.yaml to handle the font file requests. My requirement was to use custom fonts to produce a barcoded label. The font files don't have to be served tot he world and only used by the app.

```
function label()
{
    ....
    $fbarcode = './resources/ttf/FRE3OF9X.TTF';
    imagettftext($im, 75, 0, 50, 170, $black, $fbarcode, "*{$p['id']}*");
    ....

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

The font file is located in the codebase under /resources. This works both on local environment as well as on gae. Again I did *not* have to define anything in app.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved to treat the font folder when appling [cool-php-captcha](https://code.google.com/p/cool-php-captcha/) in GAE using php runtime follow the solution from Alex Alarcon i.e.:

```
- url: /(.+\.(otf|ttf|woff))$
  script: \1
```

For python solution its handler should treat remain as [default](https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098) i.e.

```
- url: /(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/opentype
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.ttf)$
```